# how to test windows phone app in an windows phone device

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have developed a windows phone application that makes use of mspn service. Its working fine with windows phone emulator. Now i wish to test it in a windows phone device. I have a windows phone device with me. What are the various steps in testing my app in a windows phone device. What are the main differences between testing my app in windows phone emulator and real device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major difference between testing on the emulator and a real device is performance, I have been bitten by this one - it all runs fine on the emulator on a powerful desktop machine, but crawls on the real device.

To test on a real device you have to sign up as a developer at the Microsoft AppHub (http://create.msdn.com) and pay your $99 - you can then unlock your phone, so you can load your app onto the phone using Visual Studio and Zune.

HTH - Rupert.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the performance gap, testing in a real windows phone device shows you how your app will behave in a real scenario.

I've found that reliability of internet connected apps decreases a lot on the real device, because of many factors. You will see triggered a lot of network-related exceptions, dns, and timeouts that your emulator couldn't see. Its a very healthy practice to test in a real device.

First of all you need your device to be "developer unlocked". You can do it by signing up to the Microsoft App Hub. If it happens that your country it not listed under the App Hub Developer program, it's not the end of the world. You can sign up with a global publisger that will give you access to the app hub under limited priviledges. I name a few ones:

Region / Name  / Web Site

APAC    **App Port**       http://www.app-exchange.com

CEE     **APPA Market**    http://appamarket.com

CHINA   **MTel**           http://wp.mtelnet.com

CHINA   **Device7**        http://www.device7.com

MEA     **Yalla Apps**     http://www.yallaapps.com

After you develop unlock your device you only need to plug in your device and visual studio will recognize your phone.

So, next to your debug button you will be able to chose between Windows Phone Emulator and Windows Phone Device. Just run and visual studio will deploy your app into your device.

Last but no least, make sure Zune software is open. And you phone screen is unlocked.

You will be surprised on how easy is to make in-device debugging.